# JPanel how to add a ToolTipText

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, tooltip

I have a little problem, I need to add a `ToolTipText` to `JPanel`. How should I do this?
I want to have a tooltip when I have mouse over the circle.
This is part of my code.

```
JPanel component1 = new JPanel();
JPanel component11 = new JPanel();
okno.add(component1,"align left,cell 0 0, h 75!, grow,wrap");


component1.setLayout(new MigLayout("","[][grow][grow]", "[grow]"));
component1.add((okno.add(creLab("Kraj", i, czcionka, etykietki))),"left align, cell 0 0");
component1.add(t1,"cell 1 0,grow");
//component1.add(new circle1(),"right align, cell 2 0,h 50!, w 53!, gapleft 50, wrap");
component1.add(component11," right align, cell 2 0, h 30!, gapleft 300, wrap");
component11.setLayout(new MigLayout("","[]","[]"));
component11.add(new circle1(),"cell 0 0,h 50!, w 50!, dock north");
component11.setToolTipText("<html>W polu obok wpisz kraj pochodzenia towaru</html>");
```

I add also code of `circle1`:

```
class circle1 extends Applet{
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        setForeground(Color.yellow);
        g.drawOval(0, 0, 50, 50);
        g.fillOval(0, 0, 50, 50);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString("Jak", 14, 14);
        g.drawString("wpisac", 3, 28);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawString("kraj?", 14, 42);


        //g.drawString(arg0, arg1, arg2)
    }
}
```

Comment: `class circle1 extends Applet` ... what made you think extending `Applet` was the right way to go ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is to identify when the mouse is inside the circle. To do that you could verify the mouse position on a mouseMotionlister according to the circle area

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JPaneladdMouseMotionListenerMouseMotionListenerlis.htm

Once you identify this situation you could proceed to change the tooltip

Comment: If you don't require an exact area calculation you can even assume a square area instead and your implementation could be even easier

Comment: It works only 'around the border' because you are using 'mouseEntered'! If you want it to work in the whole panel then just delete the comment in 'mouseMoved' and verify if you are inside the panel or not.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`JComponent#getToolTipText(MouseEvent)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getToolTipText%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29)

This will allow you to determine what text to return based on the location of the mouse.

It's difficult to determine for your code snippet, exactly where the circle is been drawen, but I would avoid drawing directly to the surface of the applet, but instead use a custom component (like a `JPanel`) instead (overriding its `paintComponent` method). This I would then either add to the applet or to the control panel.

This way your going to avoid issues with the mouse events been consumed

I would also take a look at [`Ellipse2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.html), which can be used to determine if the ellipse contains a given point

Answer (score 1):

See [Playing With Shapes](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/). You can create a JLabel with a ShapeIcon. Then you just use the `setToolTipText()` method of the JLabel. You can then add the label to the panel like any other component.

Now that you can use a component to represent a Shape there is no need to do custom painting. Just create a panel add add components to the panel. You can also create JLabels for all your text strings.

Don't do custom painting, unless you have a good reason to do so.